# Removing every occurrence of some value from a Python list?

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
a = [1,2,3,43,43,43]

count = a.count(43)
if count > 0:
    for i in range(count):
        a.remove(43)

print a
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: This is also not a great algorithm. Every time you do `a.remove(43)` Python starts at the beginning of the list again, so you are testing the values [1,2,3] over and over. In big-O notation this is O(n^2). The answers below using a simple list comprehension are O(n)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
a = [x for x in a if x != 43]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 43, 43, 45]
>>> iter = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x != 43, a)
>>> list(iter)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Generally list comprehensions and generator expressions are better.

Comment: `itertools` is a nice bunch of tools built over the standard generator tools. It's very useful but a tad overkill for this specific problem I think.

Answer (score 3):

Note that all the solutions above (except the one using remove, but that one has non linear execution time) will create a new list, and not modify the original one in place. This may or may not be a problem in your case. If you want to modify the original list, you have to use a slice assignment, such as:

```
a[:] = [value for value in a if value != 43]
```

Comment: Why is slice assignment necessary here?

Comment: as I say in the comment above the code, this is if you want the original list to be modified. This can be of importance if the list was passed as an argument in a function and you expect the function to have the side effect of modifying the list seen by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Is what you want just to remove all 43s in the list `a`?

```
a = [x for x in a if x != 43]
```

Comment: Little typo there? Shouldn't it be `[x for x in a..` rather than `[a for x in a...`?